# Extract custom decimal part in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to extract numbers as explained below:

```
Data entry as follows: DZN.Numbers
Numbers go from 0-11
(for eg:)
0.1 means 1 number
.....
0.9 means 9 numbers
0.10 means 10 numbers
0.11 means 11 numbers
```

If I use mod function I get the decimal/number part but
**The problem happens only when I have to distinguish between 0.1(1 number) and 0.10(10 numbers)**
What logic can I use in google sheets to extract the number from entered data?
Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"", "\.(\d+)")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: player0, That's just what I wanted. would like to add that column A should be formatted as text instead of number. Now I would like sum up the output of regextract without creating a new column as you have shown above[ something like sumifs(regextract..) ]. Asking since I am learning the ropes of google sheets now. Kudos..

Comment: try: `=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"", "\.(\d+)"))*1))`